# For $a \in \mathbb Z$, $3\mid a$ if and only if $3\mid a^ 2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification

For $a \in \mathbb Z$, $3\mid a$ if and only if $3\mid a^2$?

I don't get how to solve this question.

how would you prove this question?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Since $3$ is prime, $a\equiv0\pmod3\iff a^2\equiv0\pmod3$

Answer (score 3):

$3|a$ means $a=3k$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$, so $a^2=3ka$; i.e., $3|a^2$.

On the other hand, if $3|a^2,$ then by [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) $3|a$ or $3|a$; i.e., $3|a$.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, let's do this without invoking the fact that $3$ is prime, but instead using the algebraic identity $a^2-1=(a-1)(a+1)$.

It's a general fact for integers that if $d\mid a$ then $d\mid ab$ (i.e., if $a=dm$ then $ab=dm'$ where $m'=mb$), so $3\mid a\implies 3\mid a^2$ is easy.

Another general fact is that any integer $d\ge1$ divides precisely one of any $d$ consecutive integers, so if $3\mid a^2$, then $3\not\mid a^2-1$, which in turn implies $3\not\mid a-1$ and $3\not\mid a+1$ (as the converse of the previous paragraph's general fact).  But $a-1$, $a$, and $a+1$ are three consecutive integers, so if $3\not\mid a-1$ and $3\not\mid a+1$, then we must have $3\mid a$. Thus $3\mid a^2\implies 3\mid a$.

Comment: So "any integer $d\ge1$ divides precisely one of any $d$ consecutive integers" is a more elementary (primitive) concept than Euclidean division. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

$3|a^2$

We can write this as,

$a^2=3k$

Taking square root on both sides

$a=\sqrt{3k}$

$a$ is an integer, so $3k$ must be a perfect square, then $k=3t^2$ for some $t$

$a=\sqrt{9t^2}$

$a=3t$

$3|a$

Answer (score 0):

It is immediate that

$3 \mid a \Longrightarrow 3 \mid a^2, \tag 1$

as has been so eloquently demonstrated by our friend J.W. Tanner in his answer to the question.

On the other hand, suppose that

$3 \mid a^2, \tag 1$

but

$3 \not \mid a; \tag 2$

then since $3$ is prime,

$\gcd(3, a) = 1; \tag 3$

thus by Bezout's identity there exist

$x, y \in \Bbb Z, \tag 4$

with

$3x + ay = 1; \tag 5$

we multiply through by $a$:

$3ax + a^2 y = a; \tag 6$

but now by assumption (1) we have

$3 \mid 3ax, \; 3 \mid a^2 \Longrightarrow 3 \mid a, \tag 7$

contradicting (2); thus

$3 \mid a \tag 8$

and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

It is fun proving things using elementary concepts. Below recourse is made to the binomial theorem and Euclidean division theorem.

See Barry Cipra's answer - it 'lightens the machinery' still further, using two 'step-down' ideas in which the word *theorem* does not appear.

---

For the more interesting direction of the equivalence, assume that $3 \nmid a$. Then applying [Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) we can write as true

$\tag 1 a = 3 q + r \quad \text{ where } r = 1 \text{ or } r = 2$

When $r = 1$

$\quad a^2 = (3 q + 1)^2 = 3 \times 3 \times q^2  +  3 \times 2 \times q + 1 = 3 (3 q^2  +  2q) + 1$

and using Euclidean division theory we conclude that $3 \nmid a^2$.

When $r = 2$

$\quad a^2 = (3 q + 2)^2 = 3 \times 3 \times q^2  +  3 \times 4 \times q + 4= 3 (3 q^2  +  4q + 1) + 1$

and, again, using Euclidean division theory we conclude that $3 \nmid a^2$.

Answer (score 0):

The nontrivial part is a special case of *Euclid's lemma*, since $3$ is prime. The other direction, $3|a\implies 3|a^2$, is trivial.

Euclid's lemma is in fact pretty trivial, too, if you know the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, say.